# Defining "structured sets"

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

In his [Notes on Set Theory](http://books.google.de/books/about/Notes_on_Set_Theory.html?id=eaPY47H79QIC) (p. 44) Moschovakis defines:

> A **structured set** is a pair $U = (A,S)$ where $A$ is a set, the *space* of $U$,
>   and $S$ is an arbitrary object, the *frame* of $U$.

But even when $S$ is allowed to be something else than a set, this is hardly a definition like

> A **graph** is a pair $(V,E)$ with $E \subseteq V \times V$

or

> A **topological space** is a pair $(X,T)$ with $T \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ ...

because nothing is imposed on the relationship between $A$ and $S$. The "definition" looks like the definition of (the notion of) an ordered pair, and at most it's a necessary condition for structured sets.

But how *can* one require that the frame $S$ is not an *arbitrary* object but has to *do* with the underlying set $A$ (to be able to endow some structure on it)?

Looking at the typical examples of algebraic and relational structures and of topological spaces one might tend to require that $S$ is a tupel $(S_1,\dots,S_n)$ with $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash S_i \in X_i(A)$ where $X_i(A)$ is a set constructed over $A$ solely by iterating the set operations $\mathcal{P}$ and $\times$. (This seems to be the [Bourbakian way](http://books.google.de/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=bourbaki%20theory%20of%20sets&hl=en&ei=0R__Tam2DIbDtAaLuZnyDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=species%20of%20structures&f=false) of echelons.)

But how would this restriction be justified? Why not requiring that $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash \phi(S_i,A)$ for an *arbitrary* formula $\phi(X,Y)$?

OK, this would not do the job, because $X = X \wedge Y = Y$ is such a formula but doesn't induce a genuine relationship between $X$ and $Y$ like e.g $X \subseteq Y \times Y$ does.

> 1. Can we characterize a truely general family of formulas $\phi(S_i,A)$ that *do* induce such a relationsship – beyond those of the form $S_i \in X_i(A)$?
> 2. Suppose we can: Can we make this characterization into a first-order definition of "structured set"?

The second question has to do with the fact that one cannot give a first-order definition of "[definable sets](https://mathoverflow.net/a/65641/2672)" but e.g. of "[constructible sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe)".

Comment: Since Moschovakis is defining his term *structured set*, the definition is (by definition!) a necessary **and** sufficient condition for something to be a structured set. What you appear really to be saying is that you think that the name is not appropriate for the thing being defined.

Comment: I agree in parts: I double-checked if Moschovakis explicitly terms it a **definition** (he doesn't), so I am allowed to read it as a necessary condition.

Comment: I don’t think that you are: it seems perfectly clear from the discussion that he is defining the term, whether he explicitly says so or not.

Comment: In my opinion the thing Moschavakis would have defined was: an ordered pair. (With the caveat that $S$ is an "object", and not a set.)

Comment: The actual text contradicts your opinion. He is defining the term *structured set*; the definition is slightly informal, owing to his use of the term *object*. His definition of *ordered pair* is elsewhere. And he explicitly notes that a structured set could even be an atom, in which case it is certainly **not** an ordered pair.

Comment: This means: every ordered pair is a structured set?

Comment: It appears to, yes.

Comment: I didn't want to restrict myself to Kuratowski pairs. Cannot there be arbitrary definitions of ordered pairs which allow an ordered pair to be an atom?

Comment: Actually, he allows any notion of *ordered pair* that satisfies the appropriate conditions, so yes, an ordered pair could be an atom.

Comment: So we are going round in circles: an ordered pair could be an atom,  so also a structured set - as an ordered pair - can be.

Comment: I don’t see any circles. He’s defining *terminology*. Assuming that $U$ is a set, whether you call $(U,\mathscr{S})$ an ordered pair or a structured set will depend on context, on what you want to say about it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11131/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-brian-m-scott)

Comment: I don’t see any real point: I’ve said what I wanted to say, namely, that the definition **is** a definition, not a ‘definition’, and that it therefore gives both a necessary and a sufficient condition for something to be a structured set as Moschovakis is defining the term. Your statement to the contrary is simply wrong. I understand that you would prefer a notion that requires the frame to have something to do with the universe, and the rest of the question is fine, but I’m not interested in it.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks anyhow.

Comment: You’re welcome. (I really didn’t expect to provoke quite such a long string of comments!)

Comment: Don't see it as a provocation: it was a pleasure - and insightful - for me. (Even though I am not finally satisfied.)